# Powershell Try Catch with ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: sql, powershell, error-handling, runtime-error

I'm working on a powershell script that will execute a Script across multiple servers.
after converting my script to an exe using http://ps2exe.codeplex.com/

I get an error, if any errors are caught in the try catch, when I close the window.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
    $dataAdapter = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand ($ExeStatement, $connString);
    $dataAdapter.Connection.Open();
    $dataAdapter.CommandTimeout = 65535;
    Try {
        $dataAdapter.ExecuteNonQuery()}
    catch{
         $ErrorCounter = $ErrorCounter + 1
         $dataAdapter.Connection.Close();}
    finally{
         $dataAdapter.Connection.Close();}
```

If I remove the try catch I am able to close the window just fine when errors are caught.
If I remove the $dataAdapter.CommandTimeout = 65535; I am able to close the window just fine when errors are caught, but I need this as one of the scripts is fairly long.
If I set the ErrorActionPreference to STOP it works just fine as well.  Though I want to to be able to continue through the errors and report at the end.

I get the following error from windows when closing my window.

> Description:   Stopped working
>
> Problem signature:
> Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
> Problem Signature 01: PROGRAMNAME.exe
> Problem Signature 02: 0.0.0.0
> Problem Signature 03: 53bdc0d9
> Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
> Problem Signature 05: 2.0.0.0
> Problem Signature 06: 5174de33
> Problem Signature 07: 34a9
> Problem Signature 08: 18c
> Problem Signature 09: System.IO.IOException
> OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.16.7
> Locale ID:    1033
> DefaultDataCollection failed: 0x8007001f

I need the script to be able to continue through the error, but I also need to catch the error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the OP solved this already, but for anyone who stumbles across it, the likely fix is that he tries to close the data adapter twice when he catches an error: once in the catch block and once in the finally block, but it has already been closed in the catch block.

The OP notes that this only happens when he has an error. Yes, because that's the only condition that leads to the double close.

The easy answer is to remove the data adapter close from the catch block and let the finally block take care of it.

Comment: Please provide the suggested response as an example, that's better.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you remove the 'finally' block and just close the connection?

```
        try {
            $dataAdapter.ExecuteNonQuery()
        }
        catch {
            $ErrorCounter = $ErrorCounter + 1
        }
        $dataAdapter.Connection.Close()
```

or

```
        try {
            $dataAdapter.ExecuteNonQuery()
            $dataAdapter.Connection.Close()
        }
        catch {
            $ErrorCounter = $ErrorCounter + 1
        }
```

Does your exec return anything when it completes without error? Maybe alter it to return a 0 or something when it's done running. My guess is the adapter is waiting for something to return (even though it's not a query), therefore if there's no error you never reach the finally block and close the connection.

Comment: It only causes issues when when an error returns, if I throw the close outside of the catch, or inside the try I get the same error.

Comment: If ExecuteNonQuery gives an error, Connection.Close will never be executed (second case). On second one, Connection.Close can be executed only if $dataAdapter has been pre-defined outside of try-catch (on this case should work, but is better to comment for future references).